# Comparing integers and decimals in bash

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am trying to compare two numbers stored in variables in a shell script. The objective is to find if the incoming value is inside the specified ranges: `500-600` or `700-800`.

My current code looks like:

```
inc=0
srange[0]=500 
erange[0]=600
srange[1]=700 
erange[1]=800

for i in "${startrange[@]}"; do
    if [[ " ${startrange[$inc]} " -lt " $actual " ]]; then
        echo " in range "
    fi
    inc = $((inc+1))
done
```

The code works with integer values such as `530` or `540` but fails with decimal values like `530.2` or `540.3`, resulting in a syntax error on this line of the code:

```
 if (( " ${startrange[$inc]} " -lt " $actual " )); then
```

How can I fix this to handle the decimal values?

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: Your question implies you're using a shell with arrays and `((`. I would guess `bash`. Please indicate which shell you're using and update the tags for the question.

Comment: use bc or awk, also try using the search function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell can only do integer calculations. If you want to compare values that are non-integers, you must use a tool that can understand decimal math. `bc` is one such option:

```
if bc <<< "${startrange[inc]} < $actual"; then …
```

Comment: Won't accept decimals just like OP's won't

Comment: i assumed that was their attempt to stop the syntax error as the if in their actual code would work the same as your answer.

Comment: Also i can't check atm but I'm pretty sure you can use quotes inside `(())`

Comment: @kojiro Are you sure i'm almost 100% that you can use quotes however you like in `(())`. Also yes the title is slightly misleading!

Comment: @123 I'm sure of what I'm saying, but I'm not sure of what meaning you're taking from it. Compare `x=123; echo $(( "$x" ))` and `x=123; echo $(( " $x " ))`.

Comment: That's shell arithmetic, not  `let` or `(())`, spaces matter in shell, not in let.

Comment: @123 huh, you're right! Good eye.

Comment: It's covered in the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Concept-Index_cp_letter-A). Arithmetic Expansion says "a double quote inside the parentheses is not treated specially." _Shell Arithmetic_ is ever so slightly different.

Comment: Arithmetic expansion uses shell arithmetic, and "a double quote inside the parentheses is not treated specially."  just means that quotes are treated normally as in they allow spaces to be part of the string, which is incidentally incorrect syntax for shell arithmetic. The `(())` is actually the `let` command and handles spaces( i assume) by just removing/ignoring them after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're saying that your code works for integer numbers but not for decimal numbers.

In that case you could simply turn all your numbers into integers before you do the comparison to avoid that error.

This is one way to turn decimals to integers in bash:

```
DECIMAL=3.14
INTEGER=${DECIMAL%.*}
```

Note that if you used this code to try to turn an integer into an integer it would return the same number so you can apply this to any number you get regardless of whether or not it is a decimal.